# How get the selected value in DropDownList with Jquery and c#

Tags: c#, jquery

Hello again with the same detail a few days ago, I hope I can give more ideas to see that I have the error.

I want to get the selected value from a `DropDownList` and show it to me on an alert, this I am doing with jQuery and C#

The code I have in alertprefa.js is as follows:

```
$(function () {
    $('#ddlTerminal').change(function () {
        var text = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
        alert(text);
    });
});
```

I also added my .js to my form

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/alertprefa.js"></script>
```

Comment: You have a typo - remove the space in the `option:selected` selector. Also note it should be `var`, `text()` and `alert()`, not `Var`, `Text()` and `Alert()` as JS is case sensitive.

Comment: Thank you, an apology at the time of placing it I left the space I have it as follows $(function () { $('#ddlTerminal').change(function () { var text = $(this).find('option:selected').text(); alert(text); }); });

Comment: You are going to want to update your question with the js you just put in a comment, and post your html as well.

Comment: @Molitaa as Gavin says, please edit your question to show your *actual* code. Also, if that is your code then it should be working fine. Check the console for errors.

Comment: I have already changed the code

Comment: Thanks for the help, what was missing was to place an identifier in the DropDownList

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something, And the difference between text and value if you need.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('select').change(function() {

    alert("value: " + $(this).val() + "   Text: " + $(this).find('option:selected').text());

  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="0">Nothing</option>
  <option value="1">Item1</option>
  <option value="2">Item2</option>
  <option value="3">Item3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution but my alert does not appear. And I see that in yours yes, I'm missing something

Comment: Thanks for the help, what was missing was to place an identifier in the DropDownList

Thanks.

Comment: If it helped you, Mark it as answer, OR if you solved it urself, post your answer and close this questions as solved.